# Facebook login with Socialite throws error

Tags: laravel, oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to integrate facebook login into an app just for learning purposes but it seems that facebook made some changes recently that allows only https.

Here's the error when I try to log in with facebook:

```
Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://
```

Some people suggested to go to Facebook Login -> Settings and disable 'Enforce HTTPS for Web OAuth Login'. However, it seems that the recent update on facebook disabled this option.

Anyone found a work around this problem?

Comment: why don't you just use HTTPS then? Is there a reason not to?

Comment: _“However, it seems that the recent update on facebook disabled this option.”_ - can’t confirm. Please double-check you actually made this setting for the correct app id.

Comment: It's the correct app id. I just checked.

Comment: according to the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#surfacearea)  "All new apps created as of March 2018 have this setting on by default", I've created a new app and I confirm `Enforce HTTPS` is disabled even in `create test app`, pretty weird. Old apps don't have this issue

Answer (score 1):

[Enforce HTTPS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#surfacearea)
This setting requires HTTPS for OAuth Redirects and pages getting access tokens with the JavaScript SDK. All new apps created as of March 2018 have this setting on by default and you should plan to migrate any existing apps to use only HTTPS URLs by March 2019. Most major cloud application hosts provide free and automatic configuration of TLS certificates for your applications. If you self-host your app or your hosting service doesn't offer HTTPS by default, you can obtain a free certificate for your domain(s) from [Let's Encrypt.](https://letsencrypt.org/)